# What is the functionality of method called class in objective-C

Tags: objective-c, initialization, self

Hi I was studying about **initialize** class method in objective-C. I came across this code which confused me

```
+ (void)initialize {
    if (self == [Car class]) // what is the use of method class??
    {
        // Makes sure this isn't executed more than once
        _defaultModel = @"Nissan Versa"; // initializing the static variable  _defaultModel
    }
}
```

Here I know that we're using **if (self == [Car class])** to check whether  the **self** is referring to class itself or not. But what is the functionality of method **class** in **[Car class]** . I'm a newbie and I'm learning objective-C from couple of weeks when I searched for answers for this question all i got is difference b/w class methods and instance methods which I know. So please tell me what is the functionality of method **class**. Thanks in advance .

Comment: You can use this "class"-function to test if the object on the other side of the equation is of the same type

Comment: And if you were to do this (the equals check) in a instance method you need to do [self class] == [Car class] since self is bound to the instance rather then the class in a instance method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two things to note here.

First, as you say the code is "using `if (self == [Car class])` to check whether the self is referring to class itself or not". The method `class` returns the class object for `Car`, and `self` will be the same object if `initialize` is being called on `Car`.

Second, how could the class method `initialize` of `Car` be called on anything other than `Car` itself - it belongs to the class after all?

The answer to this lies in inheritance. The `+initialize` of `Car` will be called once before any instance of `Car` is created. However it will be also called once for *every subclass* of `Car` before the first instance of that subclass is created. E.g. if you have a class:

```
@interface Volvo : Car
...
@end
```

Then if `Volvo` has an `+initialize` then it will be called before the first instance of `Volvo` is created *and* `Car`'s `+initialize` will also be called before the first instance of `Volvo` is created. This is why you will often see class initializers with an `if` statement to check for `self` being the class itself - it ensures the code is only executed once and not once per subclass as well.

HTH

Answer (score 1):

```
[NSObject class]
```

Returns the class type of the object. See Apple's [API](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/classes/NSObject_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSObject/class)

(By the way as a side note it's always good to google for the API before asking questions here)

Comment: Ya I googled it but while I was reading apple docn about initialize I saw this :
`+ (void)initialize {
  if (self == [ClassName self]) {
    // ... do the initialization ...
  }
}`
here they had used [ClassName self] but in the tutorials which i was reading the had given [ClassName class] which led me to confusion. Anyhow thanks alot :)

Comment: `[ClassName self]` and `[ClassName class]` are identical. `[obj self]` and `[obj class]` are different, if `obj` is not a class object.

Answer (score 1):

There are *two* methods named `class` in Cocoa: the *class method* `+[NSObject class]`, and the *instance method* `-[NSObject class]`. They do very different things, so do not get them mixed up. The former overrides the latter for class objects.

Here you are asking about the class method `+[NSObject class]`, so that's what we will talk about. This method simply returns the object (class object) that it is called on, similar to `-[NSObject self]`. In fact, `[Car class]` can also be written as `[Car self]`.

So why do we use a method that simply returns what it was called on? Why not just use the thing it's called on directly? This is due to a peculiarity in Objective-C syntax. In Objective-C, a class name like `Car` is not a valid expression (don't know why; the gods just made it that way). So we cannot just directly write `self == Car`, even though that's what we're really trying to say.

On the other hand, Objective-C has a special case for the message sending syntax `[ ]`, where if the thing on the left side is a class name, the message is sent to the class object. So the "work-around" to get the class object for a class is to use the `[ ]` syntax to call a dummy "return self" method on it. In the Cocoa/GNUStep/OpenStep framework, there are two methods that can do this, `+class`, and `-self`. By convention, `+class` is used (which is really unfortunate, due to confusion with `-class`). After a while, you'll just get used to seeing `[SomeClass class]` and interpreting it as the `SomeClass` class object, whereas `[some_obj class]` gets the class of `some_obj` if it is not a class object.

(Note: In Smalltalk, which is where Objective-C inherited much of its stuff from, a class name *is* the expression for a class. So something like `self == Car` would be the correct way to write it. And the `class` method in Smalltalk *always* gets the class of the object, regardless of whether it's a class object or not.)